# Getting error with React App when I connect another pc

Tags: reactjs, express

I have developed react app which is connected to database and various modbus devices.
While i am trying to connect react app another pc where the same network with local pc, i am getting an error: Network error.

When first rendering, App.js requests to db and gets response from the following server code:

```
app.get("/programListele", function (req, res) {
 pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
  if (err) {
  console.log(err)
  return res.status(400).send(err);
  } else {
   db.query('SELECT * FROM public."Programlar" ORDER BY "id" ASC', function (err, table) {
    done();
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
      //db.end()
      return res.status(200).send(table.rows);       
    }
  });
}
```

**The problem is that when I run react application from the local computer, the codes run smoothly and the information returns but I get an error when I run react application from another computer.**

I tried:

1. Postgresql remote access connection is open. I can connect to db with the another pc where in same
   network.
2. I have requested to server with Postman and gotten the data without problem.

What can i do to this?

Comment: There might be some problem with the host address you are using. Are you sure you are not using ```localhost``` as your server?

Comment: What type of network error? Please share the details.

Comment: @blankart yes i was using localhost. I fixed it thank you. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instant of `http://localhost:3000` use `http://<ip address of your server machine>:3000` while connecting with the backend server.